# Why don't we measure the same parameters for LNA and OpAmp?

Tags: rf, analog, integrated-circuit

I am looking at LNA designs and OpAmp designs, and seeing as both are amplifiers, I was wondering why both don't offer the same parameters of interest.

To be specific, why isn't DC offset, Slew rate, and Input range measured for LNA and only Sparameters and NF are usually given, while it is the opposite for the OpAmp?

Comment: Add links to specific datasheets. Most likely the answer lies in the targeted applications of both parts.

Comment: All is depending on the frequency in use. Op-amps are used with "low" frequency. LNA with "high" frequencies ... and no DC.

Comment: @tobalt I am not looking at data sheets, rather looking at the design procedures for one, and I was wondering why they look at different parameters

Comment: @Antonio51 That explains the offset problems, but how about slew rate? OpAmp slew rate is important, but for LNA, we only look at S parameters

Comment: Slew rate is needed for "large signal" (> 1V) ... LNA uses only "low level" ( < ~10 uV).